# List.Add results in error

Tags: c#, list, model

So I am using ASP.net and trying to add a model/string to a List

```
public class Playlist
{

    public Playlist()
    {
        this.placeList = new List<places>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<places> placeList { get; set; }


    public class places
    {
        [Key]
        public int places_id { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am getting my id for places as a string as I want. I would expect

```
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
playlist.placeList.Add("hi")
```

would result in adding an entry into the id field but instead I get an error saying. The best overload method match for System.Collection.Generic.List has invalid arguments. So I tried creating another model.

```
public class PlaceModel2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

and adding

```
PlaceModel2 f = new PlaceModel2();
f.id = ("hi");

playlist.placeList.Add(f);
```

I thought this would've worked but this just gave me the same error. Any Clue?

Comment: Could you give us the full version off error?

Comment: So this is the error I am getting
playlist.placeList.Add(f) The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Travelfy.API.Entities.Playlist.places>.Add(Travelfy.API.Entities.Playlist.places)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
playlist.placeList.Add("hi")
```

you are trying to add `string` object to `List` of `places` objects

Here:

```
PlaceModel2 f = new PlaceModel2();
f.id = ("hi");

playlist.placeList.Add(f);
```

you are trying to add `PlaceModel2` to List of `places`

**You are mismatching types**, you need to create `places` object and add it to List. So the objects match type:

```
var f = new Playlist.places();
f.id = "hi";

playlist.placeList.Add(f);
```

If you want to add different classes objects to `placeList` you need to create classes which inherit from `places` class. Then you will be able to add derived class objects to list of base class objects.

Comment: So isn't my places() a model of playlist? Wou'dn't that mean I can't treat it as a class? Which is why I created playlistModel2 to mimic the places model?

Comment: @JuliusDoan `places` is a nested class of `Playlist` but it **is a class** so you need to treat it so. If you want to add other objects than `places` you need to create derived classes

Comment: So I understand why its not working, but I'm not understanding what I need to do to fix it. So would I need to create a new class named Places with the same objects int places_id and string id (thought this was PlaceModel2)? I can't just call List<places> f = new List<places> since its a nested class. Oh yea thanks for the quick responses

Comment: @JuliusDoan you can create new list of places, but you need to do it like this: `List<Playlist.places> f = new List<Playlist.places>`. I gave you solution BTW -> last code snippet should work

Comment: Ohh lolol. Wow I feel soo stupid that I never even tried that. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @JuliusDoan glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

In first case

```
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
 playlist.placeList.Add("hi")
```

you are adding a `string` to `List<places>` instead of `places` object

In second case

```
 PlaceModel2 f = new PlaceModel2();
 f.id = ("hi");

 playlist.placeList.Add(f);
```

you are adding a `PlaceModel2` to `List<places>` instead of `places` object.

Correct it and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Your collection has T as class places. To get it working you have to add someting like that:

```
var place = new places(){ /*initialize properties*/ };
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
playlist.placeList.Add(place);
```

Your Collection is List not List thats why it isn't working.

Comment: Since places is a nested class I can't just call new places(){  }...?

Comment: Your placeList is beign created in constructor so you can add elements. Your collection is List<places> so you have to add to this collection objects created from places class.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Places>` can hold **only a List of Places** class.

You're trying to add a string to the List of Places.

So you need to be doing something like this :

```
Places places = new Places();
places.id="hi";
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
playlist.placeList.Add(places) ;
```